# Confirm Navigation not showing my message

Tags: javascript, dom

I have used this but it is not showing my custom message instead it is showing its own message

```
<script language="JavaScript">


 var needToConfirm = true;

  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    if (needToConfirm)
      return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: try to use alert instead of return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customized message will be shown in Google chrome only, Firefox doesn't support it so far.